# Type <Type> with data contract name <contract name> is not expected

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, catel

I am using Catel Framework in a Desktop WPF app and when I try to save a model to a file I get the following error.

```
Type 'GeoChemicalFuncsCS.Core.Models.BoilingModel' with data contract name 'BoilingModel:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GeoChemicalFuncsCS.Core.Models' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
```

I tried adding the KnownType and ServiceKnownType Tag to the model, but I get:

```
KnownType could not be found.
```

or

```
ServiceKnownType could not be found.
```

And I also tried WarmingUp the SerializationFactory in the ViewModel:

```
var typesToWarmup = new Type[] { typeof(BoilingModel) };
SerializationFactory.GetXmlSerializer().Warmup(typesToWarmup);
```

but nothing changed.

Does anyone have any suggestion? What can I do at this point?

Thanks
Saul Hidalgo.

Comment: Now I get it. You are not using WCF at all. Forget what I posted before. 
What is `SerializationFactory`? Doesn't seem to be a part of the .NET framework, but it seems like it tries to use the WCF serializaton mechanisms which is probably not what you need. For simple XML serialization of objects, you should use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Are you using the latest prerelease? We made numeral improvements on Catel 4.0 (upcoming version) on the serialization engine.

Comment: Hi Geert Van Horrik.

I am trying to update to Catel 4.0 but I haven't finished. However, I think it is related with how I am serializing my objects. I say this because I also tried to serialize without using Catel and I had the same error. My code was:


`XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainWindowModel));

                            Serializer.Serialize(File.Create(AlcatrazSPCALC.Models.Constants.SaveFilePath), MainWindowModel);`

My model has other models 'inside'. What do you recommend me?

And regarding Catel 4.0. Do you recommend us to use it? Is it stable enought?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work I finally solved it.

Problem was originated because I had a collection which contained 2 types of objects (both serializable). I tried to generalize it creating a collection of "object", and when I needed to use it I casted it.

Well, serializer engine found the type "object", and when he tried to serialize, he found it really was a BoilingModel.

**Solution** was just doing an interface, and now both serializable types implement that interface.

I hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

Regards
Saul.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you (or the Catel library) are somehow trying to use the WCF `DataContractSerializer` for simple serialization of a plain object to an XML file. That is not what the `DataContractSerializer` is designed for - it's basically designed for serializing data objects to SOAP to be sent over a WCF web service, and requires complex configuration.

For simple XML serialization, annotate the class / struct to be serialized with `[Serializable]` and use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`.

Example (not tested):

```
var boilingModelObj = new BoilingModel();
// ... fill object with data ...
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BoilingModel));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("boilingmodel.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, boilingModelObj);
}
```

Comment: The models aren't "plain objects", it's all dynamic.